# Java GUI with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have 2 codes with this being the main class-

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class gui2
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       frame a=new frame();
       a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       a.setSize(275*180);
       a.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

and this one the class i am importing--

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class frame extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel first;
    public frame(){
        super("Trying GUI");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        first=new JLabel("tHIS IS  a sentence");
        first.setToolTipText("hover to see");
        add(first);
    }
}
```

When I run the code, i am getting an error that cannot access frame.What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Show the full complete error message, not your interpretation of it.

Comment: `a.setSize(275*180);` is wrong to start with

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for pointing it out. It has solved the problem. Program gave the correct output now. I missed the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi，i have ran your code in my eclipse, it was easy to see there was a compile error on gui2.java
[image]

i think you want to create a frame with 275 width and 180 height, if it is true, you shoul call method like a.setSize(275, 180)

i fixed the error, and ran again, it was OK
[image]

BTW: i suggested that , class name should be UPPERCASE like Gui2, this was recommend by java. and if you want to know why a.setSize(275 *180) was wrong, you can see the java api detail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

hope it will be helping for you

Comment: Yup. Thank you. It has worked now. I misplaced the * mark.

Comment: @ShubamBharti glad to see that

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't follow Java naming conventions, `frame` should be `Frame` *or* `MyFrame` *or* even `MainFrame`. Other than that, your code works if I change

```
a.setSize(275*180);
```

to

```
a.setSize(275, 180);
```

[image: hover to see]

Comment: I was just trying the code so naming convention was not a big issue in it